# How to convert XML to Array In PHP

Tags: php, xml, curl

I'm new in for SOAP API and i got response from web services . But i'm not able to convert it in array to get the keys.

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <ns2:setTransactionResponse xmlns:ns2="http://soap.api.controller.web.payjar.com/">
         <return>
            <merchantReference>mercRef_1395758213</merchantReference>
            <payUReference>17613281409117</payUReference>
            <successful>true</successful>
         </return>
      </ns2:setTransactionResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try the following to xml response to an array

```
 $xml = $response;
$xml = preg_replace("/(<\/?)(\w+):([^>]*>)/", "$1$2$3", $xml);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
$json = json_encode($xml);
$responseArray = json_decode($json,true);



echo "<pre>";print_r($responseArray);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [soapBody] => Array
        (
            [ns2setTransactionResponse] => Array
                (
                    [return] => Array
                        (
                            [merchantReference] => mercRef_1395758213
                            [payUReference] => 17613281409117
                            [successful] => true
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: It's in variable not in file...got from curl response

Comment: @Sudhir i have updated code try now

Comment: Also it gives syntax error

Comment: It's not recommended to mangle the XML to remove namespaces for something as simple as this.

Comment: @Sudhir which is synatx error ?